# Cakephp session is not setting in pages controller

Tags: cakephp, cakephp-1.2

I am using cakephp1.2 . I have pages_controller which extends app_controller. I have given Session component in app controller . While login from my application, Im setting the session and redirecting to pages controller, but there I could not able to get the session. If I redirect to some other controller, Im getting the session over there. I have a table with name "pages", and when the user clicks on the links (passing page name), Im taking data from that table and displaying using pages_controller. I have to use the $uses since I need to fetch data from some tables. The pages are not static.

Can I not use "pages" as table name ? Or session won't work in pages_controller ?

My core.php settings
Session.save - php
Session.start - true
Security.level - low

I have tried by changing this values.. But no result..

Comment: You're not being very specific, but if you grabbed pages_controller.php from cake/libs/controller, you would have to add the Session component to the components property (`var $components = array('Session');`) and remove `var $uses = array();`, which tells the controller not to use any tables. If you wrote your pages controller from scratch, make sure that you extended the AppController class and that you load the Session component in the AppController.

Comment: Also I wouldn't override a cakephp inherent stack. I'd make a new one as you'll avoid a huge mess of problems. I'd go with something like `Articles` or similar. The other thing is to check over your config core, as there are session settings you can change there, such as session security which will effect this.

Comment: Ok I will make more clear.. I have pages_controller which extends app_controller. I have given Session component in app controller. After login, Im setting the session from users_controller and redirecting to pages_controller, where I will fetch data from pages table. But session data is losing in pages_controller. Instead if I redirect to some other controller (ex:- contacts_controller) from users_controller, I am getting the session over there. I have to use the $uses since I need to fetch data from some tables. The pages are not static.

Comment: If your pages are not static, then you shouldn't be using the pages controller. You should be creating an MVC stack for that page or object. You also shouldn't be using `$uses` as you should have created your model relationships in your models. I would recommend, reading the tutorial and book. http://book.cakephp.org/

Answer (score 1):

Please check those models or controller pages for extra spaces (extra spaces as character) is there at the end of the page.

Answer (score 0):

You aren't redefining the components array in your pages_controller are you? That would cancel out you  loading the Session component in the app controller. If you load the Session component directly in the pages controller, does it correct the issue?